# Why does my ButtonGroup give me an "<identifier> expected" error?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I'm teaching myself about Java's swing components by creating a dialog box with three radio buttons, a text box and a "go" button. I've gotten to the point where I'm adding the Radio Buttons, and am running into an error with my code. I've got one class that calls a constructor to display the dialog box. The text field and "Go" button have no functionality yet; they're just placeholders.

When I run the code as posted below, a dialog box displays as expected, but I am able to select all three radio buttons simultaneously. Reading [Oracle's `JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) and "[How to use Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton)" documentation and tutorials, it appears that I need to apply a `ButtonGroup` to my `JRadioButtons`, which automatically groups them with a select-one-and-only-one relationship.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//
public class CreateButtonSel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ButtonSel thisButtonSel = new ButtonSel();
        final int WIDTH = 250;
        final int HEIGHT = 250;
        thisButtonSel.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        thisButtonSel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However, when I un-comment the noted code in my `ButtonSel` class, despite appearing to follow the syntax noted in the tutorial for a `ButtonGroup` returns `error: <identifier> expected` with carats under the open and close parens of my `...Button.add(...)` statements. This error, from searching stack, seems to be associated with declaring varibale improperly, or at the wrong place in the class. I can't spot that error. `import javax.swing.*` should give me access to all the Button constructors, right? Is there another I should be pulling in?

What am I missing here?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//
public class ButtonSel extends JFrame {
    JLabel buttonSelLabel = new JLabel("Select One");
    JRadioButton oneButton = new JRadioButton("One", true);
    JRadioButton twoButton = new JRadioButton("Two", false);
    JRadioButton threeButton = new JRadioButton("Three", false);
/*    comment out the following; it runs fine.
 *    uncomment, and I get the following error: 
 *
 *    error: <identifier> expected with carats under the open and close 
 *    parens of my ...Button.add(...) statements. 
 *
    ButtonGroup groupOfRadioButtons = new ButtonGroup();
    groupOfRadioButtons.add(oneButton);
    groupOfRadioButtons.add(twoButton);
    groupOfRadioButtons.add(threeButton);   
*/
    JButton approveButton = new JButton("Go");
    JTextField textDisplay = new JTextField(18);
     //
    JPanel timerPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
     //
    public ButtonSel() {
        super("ButtonTest");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(buttonSelLabel);
        add(oneButton);
        add(twoButton);
        add(threeButton);
        add(textDisplay);
        add(approveButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to execute *statements* here, but without them being in a method or constructor:

```
ButtonGroup groupOfRadioButtons = new ButtonGroup();
groupOfRadioButtons.add(oneButton);
groupOfRadioButtons.add(twoButton);
groupOfRadioButtons.add(threeButton);
```

A class only directly contains method, constructor and nested type declarations, and initializer blocks.

You should put the three statements after the declaration into the constructor - you *could* use an initializer block, but it's not generally good in terms of readability.

```
public class ButtonSel extends JFrame {
    ... other fields ...

    // Note: it's a good idea to make all fields private
    private ButtonGroup groupOfRadioButtons = new ButtonGroup();

    public ButtonSel() {
        super("ButtonTest");
        ...
        groupOfRadioButtons.add(oneButton);
        groupOfRadioButtons.add(twoButton);
        groupOfRadioButtons.add(threeButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh. Constructors alway trip me up. :) I placed them where they were because I thought they needed to be associated with the `ButtonGroup()` method. But if I understand your answer, I'm instantiating the variable (or in this case, object) `ButtonGroup()` and any parameters that are associated with or further define it are placed INSIDE the constructor. Outside the constructor I'm just creating the object, but INSIDE the constructor is where I, for lack of a better word, un-abstract that object. Am I understanding it properly?

Comment: @dwwilson66: Well, your terminology is somewhat off. You're declaring a variable called `groupOfRadioButtons` and you're giving it an initial value by calling the `ButtonGroup` constructor. But then you want to call some extra methods on the object that the variable value refers to (the `add` method, three times) - so that part needs to go in the constructor.

Comment: @dwwilson66: I've edited my answer to give a clearer idea of what I mean.

Comment: that sounds like what I meant to say. :)  That helps lots. Thanks.